# moveit_tutorials kinetic error

Tags: ros, moveit, pcl, ros-kinetic, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using moveit_tutorials in ros kinetic, ubuntu 16.04. I am using this since many months. but suddenly today I get error while catkin_make,

```
    -- Could not find the required component 'pcl_ros'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_ros" with any
  of the following names:

    pcl_rosConfig.cmake
    pcl_ros-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pcl_ros" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "pcl_ros_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "pcl_ros" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

but why should this happen, because I have not change anything? before that it was working.
........................

also, `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-pcl-ros` is giving me error,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs ros-kinetic-pcl-ros ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4.119 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23,6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs amd64 0.2.0-0xenial-20190320-175136-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions amd64 0.2.1-0xenial-20190320-175749-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen amd64 0.5.20-0xenial-20190320-081440-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-pcl-ros amd64 1.4.4-0xenial-20190320-180405-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs/ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs_0.2.0-0xenial-20190320-175136-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions/ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions_0.2.1-0xenial-20190320-175749-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen/ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen_0.5.20-0xenial-20190320-081440-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-pcl-ros/ros-kinetic-pcl-ros_1.4.4-0xenial-20190320-180405-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

............................................................................

I follow this answers [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/325039/apt-update-fails-cannot-install-pkgs-key-not-working/) to update keys but still `sudo apt update` not working with following error,

```
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial InRelease
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                    
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com lucid InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                 
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/arne-alamut/freenect/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                
Hit:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                   
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                          
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                                               
Hit:12 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                           
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                          
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrave/release/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu xenial Release  
  404  Not Found
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/arne-alamut/freenect/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Hit:19 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrave/release/ubuntu xenial Release 
  404  Not Found
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/lucid/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/arne-alamut/freenect/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrave/release/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327113/moveit_tutorials-kinetic-error/) by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-27**:
re: still having problems with `apt update`: other repositories appear to have changed keys or have other problems. `packages.ros.org` appears to be fine.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-06-27**:
what should I do as moveit_tutorials package is not working? I have posted this on moveit_tutorials github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As indicated by @gvdhoorn, the ROS package repository was found after updating the keys:

```
Hit:19 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

Next you should do a sudo apt upgrade to upgrade/install packages and maybe try again to install ros-kinetic-pcl-ros, which obviously is broken on your system.

---

Originally posted by [rhaschke](https://answers.ros.org/users/26329/rhaschke/) with karma: 71 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-06-27**:
I will try this and update here.

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2019-06-27**:
Follow the instructions on this link to update the repository keys https://discourse.ros.org/t/security-issue-on-ros-build-farm/9342/8